# Custom drag and drop in Flex Tree

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have to customize drag from Flex Tree. For that I've overridden the protected function `mouseDownHandler`:

```
override protected function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if ( event.target is ScrollThumb || event.target is Button )
    {
        return;
    }

    super.mouseDownHandler(event);

    var tree:Tree = Tree(event.currentTarget);

    if (tree.selectedItem && tree.indexToItemRenderer(tree.selectedIndex) && tree.selectedItem is Image)
    {
        var image:Image = Image(tree.selectedItem);
        var source:DragSource = new DragSource();
        var dragView:Image = new Image();
        dragView.source = drawGhost(image);
        var dragInitiator:UIComponent = UIComponent(tree.indexToItemRenderer(tree.selectedIndex));
        var ghostOffset:Point = dragInitiator.globalToLocal(new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY));
        DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, source, event, dragView, ghostOffset.x, ghostOffset.y, 1);
    }
}

private function drawGhost(image:Image):Bitmap
{
    var ghostWidth:int = image.source.width;
    var ghostHeight:int = image.source.height;

    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
    sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, ghostWidth, ghostHeight);
    sprite.graphics.endFill();

    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(sprite.width, sprite.height, false);
    bitmapData.draw(sprite);
    var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);

    return bitmap;
}
```

But I've faced with two problems:

1. If my ghost's width or height is over 300 pixels, gradient transparency appears on it. I don't need it. How could I disable this feature?
2. The second problem is less important: dragging a tree element causes vertical scrolling. Any ideas how to disable it?

Gradient transparency example:
[image: Gradient transparency example]

Comment: Can you describe what "gradient transparency appears on it" means? It's been a long time, but if I recall correctly, the "drag avatar" (aka "ghost") has an alpha (transparency) applied to it. This, I believe, is a visual cue that you're dragging the item. But I would expect that it should be made transparent regardless of the object's size.

Comment: I've added an example of my "drag avatar".

Answer (score 0):

You can disable verticalScrolling by setting `verticalScrollPolicy` to "off".

Regarding the "Gradient"-thing: Try changing the cursor for dragging in the DragManager to some custom class.